# Nisan-Wigderson generator and $\mathbf P=\mathbf{BPP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, pseudo-random-generators

In [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-405j-advanced-complexity-theory-spring-2016/lecture-notes/MIT18_405JS16_P_vs_BPP1.pdf) set of notes it is claimed that:

> If there exists a polynomial-time pseudorandom generator $G:\{0,1\}^{O(\log n)}\to\{0,1\}^{O(n)}$ that $1/10$-fools all $n^2$-size circuits, then $\mathbf P=\mathbf{BPP}$.

The proof of this is as follows: If a language $L$ is in $\mathbf{BPP}$, then there is a polynomial-time algorithm $A$ such that
$$
x\in L\implies \Pr(A(x,y)=1)>\frac23;\\
x\not\in L\implies \Pr(A(x,y)=1)<\frac13,
$$
where the probabilities extend over random strings $y$ of length polynomial in the length of $x$.

Then consider the following deterministic algorithm $B$ that:

1. Enumerate over all seeds $z\in\{0,1\}^{O(\log n)}$.
2. For each $z$, call $A(x,G(z))$.
3. Return $1$ if strictly more than half of the calls return $1$, otherwise return $0$.

It is clear that $B$ is deterministic and polynomial-time. However I'm somewhat confused on the rigor of this proof. The proof is predicated on the idea that since $G$ is a pseudorandom generator, $A$ is unable to distinguish between the output of $G$ and the uniform distribution, hence for an input $x\in L$ we would have $\Pr_{z\sim\{0,1\}^{\log n}}(A(x,G(z))=1)>2/3-1/10>1/2$.

But by assumption $G$ is only able to fool circuits of size $n^2$. What if $L$ is not recognizable by circuits of size $n^2$ (or, if $A$ cannot be represented by circuits of size $n^2$)?

Comment: You can choose the parameters in the Nisan–Wigderson generator so that it fools circuits of size $n^k$ for any $k$ of your choice. This will affect the seed length.

Comment: If you have a circuit of size $n^k$ with $k>2$, consider the input as being padded to length $n'=n^{k/2}$ with dummy variables, and use the NW generator for parameter $n'$ in place of $n$.